# How to enable asynchronous replication in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, replication, data-synchronization

I have a mongodb cluster with 3 nodes.

How can i configure the cluster for asynchronous replication in this cluster? Is there any global configuration which provides this functionality?

Comment: Replication is already asynchronous, unless you specifically use a write concern that requires waiting on replication.

Answer (score 0):

Replication is already asynchronous, unless you specifically use a write concern that requires waiting on replication - Agreed with this @joe

Mongo PRIMARY node will record all its transactions in an opslogs [Operations log] & replaying with its SECONDARY nodes, so basically its synchronise only.